# Is there a way to select the variables that contribute the most to the neural network when there are a lot of variables to choose from?

Tags: neural-networks

Is there a way to find the 'information gain' from each variable that we input into a neural network. I have 47 variables for creating a classification model. When I use them all, the model becomes horribly overfit. I am not sure how to go forward. Is selecting the right concoction of variables mostly intuition, plus trial and error? Or are there any tools for this purpose?

Any input is appreciated.

Comment: If overfitting is your main problem, it may be better idea to focus rather on regularization of your model (less units, dropout, weight decay, etc.) than removing input variables.

Comment: You most likely shouldn't use neural networks if you want interpretability. BTW methods that have probably the best interpretability like linear/logistic regression and Random Forests should also be less likely to overfit.